# Compile c file by source code

Tags: c

I'm writing a code that got a path to C file, and I want to compile the file by the program code. Meaning that the compile will not be in the command line like:

```
gcc -o a.out file.c
```

There is a way to do it?

Comment: quick and dirty, use [`system()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a program, and in that program you want to compile *another* program by "calling" the `gcc` command? Then the `system` function as mentioned above could do the work.

Comment: Or you could do something like `execv("/usr/bin/gcc", pathToSource)`

Comment: @HugoOshiro Only after doing a `fork` though.

Comment: What do you mean by “the compile will not be in the command line”? Do you mean that you want the same effect as this command, but cannot enter it at a prompt?

Comment: @joachimPileborg so what is the full command? :-)

Comment: @PJTraill i mean that i want the compile will be in the code. i send to my function path to file, i checked that this is a c file, and now i want to compile this file, via my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to compile a C source file in a programmatic manner, you can try this:

```
execlp("gcc", "gcc", "file.c", "-o", "a.out", NULL);
```

`execlp` has the advantage of searching the dirs stored in your environment `$PATH` to find the required executable. It returns `-1` if the call fails. Don't forget to `#include <unistd.h>` for this to work.

You can also get away with another simple call:

```
system("gcc file.c -o a.out");
```

This requires `#include <stdlib.h>` and will execute `gcc` by invoking `/bin/sh`.

Comment: It's because `execlp()` replaces the current process with a new one, and depending on your context you can use it with `fork()` to prevent this. However, the higher-level `system()` should take care of this for you and could be simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer popen

you can easily get the output of your command in a file pointer and do something useful with it.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen